# getline not saving all characters to string

Tags: c++, string, getline

The following program saves a list of directories to a file. The file is then read and asks the user if the folder name is a favorite or not. My problem is, the getline function does not save all the characters in the input file to a string.
Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    fstream list;
    fstream favorites;

    string command1;
    string command2;
    string file;
    string file2;
    string line;

    // Cycle through the directories outputing the list of directories to a file

    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        system("Y:");
        command2 = "dir Y:\\Blu-Rays\\";
        command2 += letters[i];
        command2 += "\\";
        command2 += " /b > Y:\\Blu-Rays\\";
        command2 += letters[i];
        command2 += "\\files.txt";
        cout << command2 << endl;
        system(command2.c_str());

        file = "Y:\\Blu-Rays\\";
        file += letters[i];
        file += "\\files.txt";
        list.open(file);

        file2 = "Y:\\Blu-Rays\\";
        file2 += "favorites.txt";
        favorites.open(file2);

        // The dir command also lists the file.txt in the file, open the file and erase the line
        while (getline(list, line))
        {
            // If the line file.txt is recognized, do not append the line to the file
            if (line != "file.txt")
            {
                list << line << endl;
                save(line);
                line = "";
            }
        }
    }

    list.close();
    favorites.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from the code:

```
dir Y:\Blu-Rays\#\ /b > Y:\Blu-Rays\#\files.txt
Current title: 2012
Do you want to save the title as a favorite? [y/n]: y
Current title: s to Kill
Do you want to save the title as a favorite? [y/n]: n
Current title: Rise of an Empire
Do you want to save the title as a favorite? [y/n]: n
```

The 4th line of the output is supposed to be 3 Days to Kill and it reads s to Kill. To follow, the fifth line is supposed to read: 300: Rise of the Empire when it reads Rise of an Empire

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Also, the English alphabet has 26 letters, not 27.

Comment: You are writing to the same file you are reading from.

Comment: Why are you using `system()` to enumerate the file system using a separate command process, instead of using  something like `boost::filesystem`, or `File(First|Next)File()` on Windows, etc to directly enumerate the files in your own code? Then you don't need the input file at all, since you will already have the filenames in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing from the same `std::fstream` simultaneously probably doesn't do what you expect it to.

A simpler solution would be to use `boost::filesystem` or `std::filesystem` to iterate through the files: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs

```
for(auto& path: fs::directory_iterator("y:\\blurays\\"))
        std::cout << path << '\n';
```